# Install (Upgrade) php7 on Ubuntu 15.10 apache2

Tags: apt, apache2, php, 15.10, php7

I am trying to upgrade my apache2 php on Ubuntu 15.10  from php5 to php7. I've read a lot of instructions, but did not understand how to do it, because a lot of instructions are for Ubuntu 14 and so some "apt-get" commands are not working.

What do I need to do on Ubuntu 15.10 to upgrade my apache's php version to php7? When trying to run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
```

I am getting the error: "ValueError: SSL support not available
"

When trying to self compile, I get the following error when running "make":

```
libtool: link: `ext/gd/libgd/wbmp.lo' is not a valid libtool object
Makefile:288: recipe for target 'sapi/fpm/php-fpm' failed
make: *** [sapi/fpm/php-fpm] Error 1
```

> I came to the cinclusion to install Ubuntu 14 lts, because Ubuntu 15 sucks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

php7 is not in the "default" repositories of Ubuntu 15.10, which leaves youn with at least two options:

1. Use a ppa anyways

   - use `ppa:ondrej/php` if you want php5 and php7 to coexist
2. Compile php7 yourself

Comment: updated my question with some "error reports" from things i've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably missing HTTPS support in apt. So run `sudo apt-get install apt-tranport-https` before adding the PPA.

Comment: already installed, still getting the same error. It is thrown at "File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 148, in urlopen
    raise ValueError('SSL support not available')"..Ubuntu15 sucks

Comment: That package is not found on my Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10 eoled more than year ago. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2016/07/28/ubuntu-15-10-wily-werewolf-end-of-life-reached-on-july-28-2016/